Gradle Classpath for Groovy classes
In project GroovyFX doing gradle build I get this error:
C:\Temp\groovyfx\src\main\groovy\groovyx\javafx\canvas\FillArcOperation.groovy: Could not find class for Transformation Processor groovyx.javafx.beans.FXBindableASTTransformation declared by groovyx.javafx.beans.FXBindable

Both classes FxBindableASTTransformation and FXBindable are in the same package, in the source code.
How do I fix the classpath in Gradle, so this classes are on the classpath?
